# Is there a way of labelling bones with text?

Tags: rigging, interface

I'm looking for an easier way of labelling control bones in my rig than having to create text objects and using them as custom shapes for the bone. Is there a simple way to add a label to bones (or objects) that will show up in the viewport?

Answer (score 1):

1. In the Bone Properties, type the name you want...

[image]

2. Go to the object data properties of the armature and under viewport display, tick names

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for the viewport. Select the armature object and enable *Object Data Properties > Viewport Display > Show [X] Names*:

[image: armature with bone names]

It can get a bit messy when you zoom out.